# Keeping old database with new website design -Magento

Tags: magento

I am looking few experts in magento to put there valuable suggestions in decision making .

my client wants to update the design of each and every page ,
so I can easily install new magento and integrate the designs ,

but the problem here is he wants all his products and ordered items,
customers to be maintained in updated site.

Can any1 heps with this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a new installation of Magento to change the design, because design and programming logic is separated.

You can keep your shop with its database and all of its product, customers, orders, etc, and download and install a new package/theme.

You can adjust your theme in the backend: system -> configuration -> design

Upgrade to new version of Magento is also possible without effects on design.

Comment: i forget to mention he also wanted to upgrade store to 1.8 edition,
hence i am stucked in decision to do design change from configuration.

Comment: Design package is also compatible for upgrade